# Can I have several similar foreign keys in one table?

Tags: mysql, database, erd

I am developing a management system for a fitness gym. I couldn't get to identify how to visualize my workout plans in a DB. I have this idea (see image below) where I have a plan table and an exercise table.

[image]

The idea here is that in every plan, there are 21 exercises (9 for upper, 9 for lower, and 3 for abdominals). This is because a plan has 3 days, and for each day is a different 3-exercise plan for the upper and lower body and a different abdominal exercise each day. Am I doing this right by putting 21 foreign keys of the same exercise ID into the plan table? And if I am doing this right, how do I connect this in an ER diagram? Do I have to connect each foreign key or do I just have to put one cardinality between the two tables?

Answer (score 1):

No you are not doing it right, you are missing a table from your database model.

Do this:

`Plan -> Plan_Exercises -> Exercises`

- `Plan_Exercises` table has a `Plan_Id` column with a Foreign Key constraint to the Primary Key Id column on `Plan` table
- `Plan_Exercises` table has a `Exercise_Id` column with a Foreign Key constraint to the Primary Key Id column on `Exercise` table

Plan needs a one to many relationship to exercises, adding the "middleman" `PLan_Exercises` table provides this relationship.

Comment: Plan_Exercises would also have rank field of some kind, if the order of exercises is important

Comment: But in the system I need to choose 3 upper exercises, 3 lower exercises, and 1 abdominal for day 1 of a certain plan, and do the same for day 2 and 3. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Well now you are kind of asking someone to do it for you, my answer has launched you to the next level of relationship database design. I will give you a hint, you need even more than 3 tables in your relationships, Plans -> _Plan_Days -> Plan_Exercises -> Exercises

Comment: @BrianOgden I was thinking if I could put a "day" field in the Plan_Exercises table if that would be plausible. Now I got the queries to worry about XD thanks for your help!

Comment: @therealtsuki no problem, I hope it is making more sense to you, it is an art and a science like all software engineering ;)

Comment: Using a pivot table is the best practise. Let's imagine you add another exercise for a plan, You'll have to add a column. By using the intermediate table it avoids it. 
Concerning your question on adding data on the intermediate table, it's possible, you just have to change your database relationship. Here is a basic ERD which does this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7prB.png